# String.Join doesn't accept IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a method with this signature:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(string s, int length)
```

And I am trying to use it with `string.Join` like this:

```
var combinations = GetCombinations(text, 2);
string result = string.Join(", ", combinations);
```

But I get the following compiler error:

`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`

Can't `string.Join` take an `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: @MitchWheat How would that solve anything? It would make matters even worse ;-) String.Join expects a string-**array**, not a string, as second argument; *exactly* what the compiler is telling the user with that specific error.

Comment: steady on. I meant to say ToArray() (which is why I quickly deleted the comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call .ToArray on it?

```
String.Join(", ",combinations.ToArray());
```

**EDIT**

Also see [Dan J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020827/215042): Since .Net 4 an overload of String.Join **does** accept an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 7):

What version of the .NET Framework are you using? The [overload of String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) that accepts an IEnumerable instead of an array was added in .NET 4.